# Heroku clock process keeps crashing

Tags: flask, heroku, apscheduler

I'm trying to utilize APScheduler to periodically check a database and send an email if needed. Unfortunately, whenever I deploy to Heroku I keep obtaining this same error. The code ran perfectly fine when I ran it locally.

This is my code:

```
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler, scheduler
#from pytz import timezone
#from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
#from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
#from models import db, User, Applications, Tasks, Contact
#from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#from flask import current_app as app

sched = APScheduler()

def send_email():
    print("Hello")
    

sched.add_job(id='Sending Email', func=send_email, trigger='interval', minutes = 1)
sched.start()
print("HelloTest")
```

I commented out most of imports it just to test the clock process without the interference of other modules.

I keep getting this error:

```
2021-12-04T07:37:14.422436+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Starting process with command `python /app/backend/clock.py`
2021-12-04T07:37:15.106399+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from starting to u
2021-12-04T07:37:16.801846+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-04T07:37:16.877624+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-12-04T07:37:16.601432+00:00 app[clock.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py:95: PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider. For more details on how to do so, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
2021-12-04T07:37:16.601448+00:00 app[clock.1]:   if obj.zone == 'local':
2021-12-04T07:37:16.604340+00:00 app[clock.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/triggers/interval.py:66: PytzUsageWarning: The normalize method is no longer necessary, as this time zone supports the fold attribute (PEP 495). For more details on migrating to a PEP 495-compliant implementation, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
2021-12-04T07:37:16.604342+00:00 app[clock.1]:   return self.timezone.normalize(next_fire_time)
2021-12-04T07:37:16.610777+00:00 app[clock.1]: HelloTest
```

Comment: What you see there is a warning, not an error. What actually crashes the process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `SCHEDULER_TIMEZONE` in the app Config, I think the default is being passed to [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) which is the library having the problem

```
app.config['SCHEDULER_TIMEZONE'] = "Europe/Berlin"
```